# Camel blueprint: enums value in header

Tags: java, enums, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to set an header using a Java Enum object, but in Camel blueprint it is automatically converted in a string instead of been used as Enum object.
In the blueprint I have this route:

```
    <route id="doOperationARoute">
        <from uri="timer://MNG?delay=5s&amp;repeatCount=1" />
        <setHeader headerName="operationName">
            <simple>${type:my.pkg.EnumOperations.OP_A}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <log message="${headers}" />
        <to uri="bean:myProcessor" />
    </route>
```

The Java enum:

```
 package my.pkg;
 public enum EnumOperations{
    OP_A
 }
```

The processor:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exc) throws Exception {

        //HERE I RECEIVE THE CAST ERROR (String cannot be casted to EnumOperation)
        EnumOperations operation=(EnumOperations)exc.getIn().getHeader("operationName");

        switch (operation) {
        case OP_A: 
            break;
        default:
            break;  
        }   
    }
}
```

I searched in the simple documentation, but nothing found. Any idea?

Comment: as your message shows, getHeader(...) returns a String. You should do this: `EnumOperations.valueOf(exc.getIn().getHeader("operationName"))`

Comment: It solves, thanks, but there isn't a way to instantiate an Enum (or more generically a specifica object type) in an header inside blueprint? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1) In your proccessor get the headr with the class type

```
EnumOperations operation = exc.getIn().getHeader("operationName", EnumOperations.class);
```

2) Use a bean instead if a Camel Proccessor and pass the enum with the @header

```
class Bean {

   public void methodName (@Header("operationName") EnumOperations operation){
     switch (operation) {
        case OP_A: 
            break;
        default:
            break;  
        }   
   }
```

}